# How to make tbody scroll of HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-table

I have a dynamic table with JSON data which I am populating with the help of JavaScript

- What I am trying to achieve is to make tbody scroll
- Which I am doing currently and it's working also but the issue is the tbody and thead layout gets mismatch grid of tbody is not matching with thead

```js
var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 274659,
    "discount": 297,
    "GST": 16479,
    "amount": 290954
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55185,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3074,
    "amount": 58281
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62513,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3306,
    "amount": 65880
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 279509,
    "discount": 68,
    "GST": 16582,
    "amount": 296125
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 53462,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3064,
    "amount": 56545
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 68651,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3492,
    "amount": 72213
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 327097,
    "discount": 539,
    "GST": 19945,
    "amount": 346605
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 59341,
    "discount": 105,
    "GST": 3370,
    "amount": 62459
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 61953,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3225,
    "amount": 65248
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 490465,
    "discount": 839,
    "GST": 28465,
    "amount": 518212
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 99212,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5567,
    "amount": 104801
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 131349,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6676,
    "amount": 138151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 594466,
    "discount": 591,
    "GST": 34374,
    "amount": 628358
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109134,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6067,
    "amount": 115223
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 127449,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6511,
    "amount": 134107
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 167811,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 9968,
    "amount": 177866
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62796,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3257,
    "amount": 66095
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 268298,
    "discount": 268,
    "GST": 15943,
    "amount": 284069
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55381,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3383,
    "amount": 58789
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 64586,
    "discount": 6,
    "GST": 3285,
    "amount": 67886
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 295544,
    "discount": 246,
    "GST": 17716,
    "amount": 313128
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 56453,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3462,
    "amount": 59939
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 65159,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3381,
    "amount": 68558
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 303778,
    "discount": 201,
    "GST": 18115,
    "amount": 321797
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 60795,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3620,
    "amount": 64431
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 54495,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2841,
    "amount": 57352
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 305223,
    "discount": 53,
    "GST": 18287,
    "amount": 323556
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55584,
    "discount": 36,
    "GST": 3207,
    "amount": 58772
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 41584,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2128,
    "amount": 43722
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 439024,
    "discount": 177,
    "GST": 25148,
    "amount": 464127
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 88009,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5090,
    "amount": 93110
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 59188,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3156,
    "amount": 62213
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 593776,
    "discount": 809,
    "GST": 33689,
    "amount": 626772
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 119723,
    "discount": 45,
    "GST": 7245,
    "amount": 126933
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 59926,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3170,
    "amount": 63119
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157580,
    "discount": 340,
    "GST": 10053,
    "amount": 167391
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 25730,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 1368,
    "amount": 27110
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 260106,
    "discount": 298,
    "GST": 15181,
    "amount": 275115
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55145,
    "discount": 19,
    "GST": 3480,
    "amount": 58633
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 36664,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 1916,
    "amount": 37920
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 478163,
    "discount": 688,
    "GST": 27138,
    "amount": 504753
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 98179,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5661,
    "amount": 103855
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 98536,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4964,
    "amount": 103519
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 277139,
    "discount": 594,
    "GST": 16406,
    "amount": 293049
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 52828,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3227,
    "amount": 56071
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 53312,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2730,
    "amount": 56061
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 329539,
    "discount": 91,
    "GST": 19882,
    "amount": 349456
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 62946,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3659,
    "amount": 66624
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 69126,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3501,
    "amount": 72643
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 443783,
    "discount": 724,
    "GST": 25712,
    "amount": 468771
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 95622,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5507,
    "amount": 101151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 107235,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5683,
    "amount": 112950
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 517922,
    "discount": 181,
    "GST": 28972,
    "amount": 546845
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 96821,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5490,
    "amount": 102334
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 94158,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4909,
    "amount": 99089
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-20",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 156224,
    "discount": 35,
    "GST": 9423,
    "amount": 165700
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-20",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 45547,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2347,
    "amount": 47905
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 289268,
    "discount": 214,
    "GST": 17613,
    "amount": 306776
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 57684,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3374,
    "amount": 61080
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 57725,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2950,
    "amount": 60682
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 395657,
    "discount": 159,
    "GST": 22808,
    "amount": 418418
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 82752,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4618,
    "amount": 87390
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 74048,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3953,
    "amount": 77922
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 302731,
    "discount": 1124,
    "GST": 17774,
    "amount": 319472
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 63555,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3565,
    "amount": 67142
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 53637,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2860,
    "amount": 56506
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 284354,
    "discount": 774,
    "GST": 16423,
    "amount": 300111
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 48130,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2857,
    "amount": 50997
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 55040,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2871,
    "amount": 57926
  }
]



let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => {
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });
    /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* background-color: #00998C */

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">
  <table id="dailySales">
  </table>
</div>
```

As my table rendering code is very long, so no need to go there. What I am doing in my css, I have already commented what I am doing

As you can see tbody layout is not matching with thead, I don't know what is wrong.

Can't I use `flex` here, and how can I use that if table width exceds the screen width I want to scroll horizontal also for that I am using `class="table table-responsive"`.

**Note**: I can't use datatable for some reasons.

**Edit** I have done this with flex but layout are overlapping.

```
  table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* background-color: #00998C */

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
#dailySales thead, #dailySales tbody {
        display: block;
    }

    #dailySales tbody {
        height: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    #dailySales tr {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
    }

    #dailySales tr td, #dailySales tr th {
        flex: 1;
        width: 200px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need `display: block`. I tried removing that and it seems to work.

Comment: removing `display:block` its not working please see the snippet on big screen

Comment: Tried on full screen too. It seems to work fine. Do you have issue with some specific browser? I am using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: i am using firfox on windows and removing `display:block` layout is coming on screen fine,but no verticall scroll is there,please check for t body

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
table thead {
    margin-right:17px;
}

table thead tr {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed
}

.wdmin{
  min-width:1366px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

but when screen less than 1900 you need to add scroll horizontal also for not overlapping value

```js
var data = [{
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 274659,
    "discount": 297,
    "GST": 16479,
    "amount": 290954
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55185,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3074,
    "amount": 58281
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-01",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62513,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3306,
    "amount": 65880
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 279509,
    "discount": 68,
    "GST": 16582,
    "amount": 296125
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 53462,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3064,
    "amount": 56545
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-02",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 68651,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3492,
    "amount": 72213
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 327097,
    "discount": 539,
    "GST": 19945,
    "amount": 346605
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 59341,
    "discount": 105,
    "GST": 3370,
    "amount": 62459
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-03",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 61953,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3225,
    "amount": 65248
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 490465,
    "discount": 839,
    "GST": 28465,
    "amount": 518212
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 99212,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5567,
    "amount": 104801
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 131349,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6676,
    "amount": 138151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 594466,
    "discount": 591,
    "GST": 34374,
    "amount": 628358
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 109134,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6067,
    "amount": 115223
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 127449,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 6511,
    "amount": 134107
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 167811,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 9968,
    "amount": 177866
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 62796,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3257,
    "amount": 66095
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 268298,
    "discount": 268,
    "GST": 15943,
    "amount": 284069
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55381,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3383,
    "amount": 58789
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 64586,
    "discount": 6,
    "GST": 3285,
    "amount": 67886
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 295544,
    "discount": 246,
    "GST": 17716,
    "amount": 313128
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 56453,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3462,
    "amount": 59939
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 65159,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3381,
    "amount": 68558
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 303778,
    "discount": 201,
    "GST": 18115,
    "amount": 321797
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 60795,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3620,
    "amount": 64431
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 54495,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2841,
    "amount": 57352
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 305223,
    "discount": 53,
    "GST": 18287,
    "amount": 323556
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55584,
    "discount": 36,
    "GST": 3207,
    "amount": 58772
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 41584,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2128,
    "amount": 43722
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 439024,
    "discount": 177,
    "GST": 25148,
    "amount": 464127
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 88009,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5090,
    "amount": 93110
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 59188,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3156,
    "amount": 62213
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 593776,
    "discount": 809,
    "GST": 33689,
    "amount": 626772
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 119723,
    "discount": 45,
    "GST": 7245,
    "amount": 126933
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 59926,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3170,
    "amount": 63119
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 157580,
    "discount": 340,
    "GST": 10053,
    "amount": 167391
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 25730,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 1368,
    "amount": 27110
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 260106,
    "discount": 298,
    "GST": 15181,
    "amount": 275115
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 55145,
    "discount": 19,
    "GST": 3480,
    "amount": 58633
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 36664,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 1916,
    "amount": 37920
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 478163,
    "discount": 688,
    "GST": 27138,
    "amount": 504753
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 98179,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5661,
    "amount": 103855
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-15",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 98536,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4964,
    "amount": 103519
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 277139,
    "discount": 594,
    "GST": 16406,
    "amount": 293049
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 52828,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3227,
    "amount": 56071
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-16",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 53312,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2730,
    "amount": 56061
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 329539,
    "discount": 91,
    "GST": 19882,
    "amount": 349456
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 62946,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3659,
    "amount": 66624
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-17",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 69126,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3501,
    "amount": 72643
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 443783,
    "discount": 724,
    "GST": 25712,
    "amount": 468771
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 95622,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5507,
    "amount": 101151
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-18",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 107235,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5683,
    "amount": 112950
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 517922,
    "discount": 181,
    "GST": 28972,
    "amount": 546845
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 96821,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 5490,
    "amount": 102334
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-19",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 94158,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4909,
    "amount": 99089
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-20",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 156224,
    "discount": 35,
    "GST": 9423,
    "amount": 165700
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-20",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 45547,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2347,
    "amount": 47905
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 289268,
    "discount": 214,
    "GST": 17613,
    "amount": 306776
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 57684,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3374,
    "amount": 61080
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-21",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 57725,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2950,
    "amount": 60682
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 395657,
    "discount": 159,
    "GST": 22808,
    "amount": 418418
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 82752,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 4618,
    "amount": 87390
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-22",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 74048,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3953,
    "amount": 77922
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 302731,
    "discount": 1124,
    "GST": 17774,
    "amount": 319472
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 63555,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 3565,
    "amount": 67142
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-23",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 53637,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2860,
    "amount": 56506
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
    "gross": 284354,
    "discount": 774,
    "GST": 16423,
    "amount": 300111
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
    "gross": 48130,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2857,
    "amount": 50997
  },
  {
    "billdate": "2018-08-24",
    "outlet": "KOLAR",
    "gross": 55040,
    "discount": 0,
    "GST": 2871,
    "amount": 57926
  }
]



let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => {
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });
    /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
table#dailySales thead,
table#dailySales tbody {
  display: block;
}

table#dailySales tbody {
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  /* Just for the demo */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Trigger vertical scroll */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* background-color: #00998C */

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: rgba(84, 83, 72, .1);
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

table thead {
    margin-right:17px;
}

table thead tr {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

table tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed
}
.wdmin{
  min-width:1900px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div align="center" class="wdmin">
  <table id="dailySales">
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hey i am trying to give `hight:100vh` so that it takes screen size but by applying this its not working

Comment: @viveksingh At which element are you tying  to apply?

Comment: where `height:280px` i am replacing that with `height:100vh` and also values are overlapping

Comment: I have edited my post with the table design i am using,please check sir

Comment: @viveksingh check updated snippet with height:80vh and screen size change to 1900px

Comment: screen size 1900px is for horizontal scroll?

Comment: @viveksingh for not overlapping value when screen size is small

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189576/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-hiren-vaghasiya).

Comment: sir this one is not solving my problem

Comment: hey sir  you there?